# How to test a function that's using a Client API function imported from another module?

Tags: testing, elixir, web-api-testing

I've been trying to figure out a way to test the following piece of code (in Elixir):

```
 defmacro __using__(_) do 
      quote do
        # API functions will be used from this client
        import Client.API 

        def list_storages do
          case list_buckets do
            {:ok, res} ->
              case res.status_code do
                200 ->
                  res.body
                  |> Friendly.find("name")
                  |> Enum.map(fn bucket -> bucket.text end)
                _   ->
                  res |> show_error_message_and_code
              end
            {:error, reason} ->
              parse_http_error reason
          end
        end
  ...
```

The problem is the `list_buckets` function is being import from the `Client.API` module (that's already being tested in another project which I can't really change anything there). My idea was to stub/mock/dummy the API functions so that they return just a dummy reply. I've tried using `defoverridable` to override the `list_buckets` function but that doesn't work since the function definition is happening in another module.

I've read the following [post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) by José Valim and that has helped test the Client.API module but I don't find a way to apply those concepts to this particular problem.

My only (and stupid) idea so far is to just reimplement every function inside the macro in a test file and use a dummy API function defined there but that feels very wrong and not helpful if there are code changes in the non-testing code.

Basically I want to test if the three possible cases are correct:

1. Receiving `{:ok, res}` and code `200` -> Outputs the correct data
2. Receiving `{:ok, res}` and another code -> Output the error message and code
3. Receiving `{:error, reason}` -> parses the HTTP error and outputs the reason for failure

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the principles from that blog post. Instead of importing `Client.Api` pass it as a last variable to `list_storages`.

```
def list_storages(api \\ Client.Api) do
  case api.list_buckets do
```

This way you don't need to change anything in your application code and you can pass dummy mock when testing the function.